# R - Select which plot to annotate

Tags: r, plot

I'm new to the R plotting system and I would like to know how can I annotate or add lines to a plot in a multi-plot. For example after these commands

```
library(datasets)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(airquality$Wind, airquality$Ozone)
plot(airquality$Solar, airquality$Ozone)
```

if I would like to add a vertical line to the second plot I simply execute

```
abline(v=10, lwd=5)
```

but how can I add that same line in the first plot? How can I select the first plot?

Comment: You need to plot `abline()` after each `plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the call for the line once per plot. Notice the difference between this:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(airquality$Wind, airquality$Ozone)
abline(v=10, lwd=5)
plot(airquality$Solar, airquality$Ozone)
```

Which yields a plot with one line in the left hand side:
[image]

And this:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(airquality$Wind, airquality$Ozone)
abline(v=10, lwd=5)
plot(airquality$Solar, airquality$Ozone)
abline(v=10, lwd=5)
```

The second code should yield the following plot:
[image]